# How to publish to SmalltalkHub from Pharo without always entering your credentials?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

Is there a way of setting the SmalltalkHub username and password in an environment variable or an external configuration file as opposed to setting them in every repository in every image? It gets old introducing them always.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the solution I eventually found.

The `MCHTTPRepository>>userAndPasswordFromSettingsDo:` already has machinery for using credentials. It looks them up in the `MCRepository.Settings` class variable where it expects to find a Dictionary. Unfortunately that class variable is never set nor referenced anywhere in the image. There is also no accessor for it.

Thus, we patch the class with an accessor method for `Settings` and then set the account information in a startup script:

```
StartupLoader default executeAtomicItems: {
    StartupAction 
        name: 'Accounts'  
        code: [ 
               Author fullName: 'AuthorName'.
               MCRepository class compile: 'settings ^Settings ifNil: [ Settings := Dictionary new.]'.
               MCRepository settings 
                   at: 'account1' 
                   put: '*smalltalkhub.com* username:password'  ]
        runOnce: true
}
```

As in @Uko's example, the script should be in in `~/Library/Preferences/pharo`.

Comment: I love this solution. You don't even need to create the new #settings method, you can assign to Settings using `#classVarNamed:put:`.

Comment: Thanks Damien! I was sure there must be a way of accessing that variable without an accessor :)

Answer (score 4):

Ciao Mircea

So to set your Author name you can use *personal.st* script from my gist available [here](https://gist.github.com/Uko/7672537#file-personal-st).

If you want to set up your credentials, you should create a similar startup action with:

```
MCRepositoryGroup default repositories
  select: [:each |
    (each isKindOf: MCHttpRepository) and:
    [each location includesSubstring: 'smalltalkhub.com' ]]
  thenDo: [ :repo |
    repo
      user: 'your_user_name';
      password: 'your_secret_password' ]
```

Comment: Thanks @Uko. Your solution only patches repos that are already defined in that image. If I add a new repository, this is still not a solution.

Answer (score 3):

It would also be nice to have one feature to actually remove all of those credentials.
This is useful when shipping images to other people so that there are no passwords in there.

Also, there is a side thing, which is that the changes file may have some passwords in it.
I am curious to know how this could be handled.